# how to use str.replace in a lambda function in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use `str.replace()`, inside a lambda function.
But I am confused, where do I pass my lambda function's parameter, while using `str.replace()`,
below are the details

Input:

```
name_1
john&&
mary&&
tim&&
```

Expected Output:

```
new_name
john
mary
tim
```

Code:

```
df1=pd.read_csv('names.txt',sep='\t')
df1['new_name'] = df1['name_1'].apply(lambda a: str.replace('&&',''))
```

Error:

```
replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: first off, i dont think u need an anonymous function to use string replace. u can just pass it to the line df1.name1.str.replace(...). for usage of arguments with apply, have a read here: [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html)

Comment: you don't need `apply` here the issue you have is that your using a method on nothing - you'd need to prepend a - just do `df['name_1'].str.replace('&&', '')`

Comment: df1.name1.str.replace(...) works fine i already did it, but i need it in lambda because i want to further write, based on lambda. Or can you suggest how to use "or" in str.replace, Example str.replace('&&'| or '##', ' ')

Comment: df1.name1.str.replace(r'&|or','') should work. the | stands for or

Comment: Hope `df1['new_name'] = df1['name_1'].apply(lambda a: a.replace('&&',''))` works!

Answer (score 4):

As others mentioned in the comments, you can simply use str.replace

```
df1['new_name'] = df1['name_1'].str.replace('&&','')
```

OR

```
df1['new_name'] = df1['name_1'].apply(lambda a: str(a).replace('&&',''))
```

If you insist having lambda function, it will work no matter values in `df1['name_1']` is a string or not. The trick is to appoint `a` as a string before you apply `replace(,)`
If you wish to replace a single unicode, try:

```
df1['new_name'] = df1['name_1'].apply(lambda a: str(a).replace(u'\u0027',''))
```

Because of my shallow knowledge, I am not aware of any builtin that can replace a range of unicodes(I am not saying it does not exist!), but if you also can't find any you might considering writing a loop. Read this:[replace multiple strings](https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-replace-single-or-multiple-characters-in-a-string/)

I hope it helps!

Comment: it works, when we pass '&&' explicitly. But does not work when i pass unicode ranges: df1['new_name'] = df1['name_1'].apply(lambda a: str(a).replace('[\u0021-\u0027]+',''))

Comment: I edited my answer, although I am not sure if it is helpful enough!